# How to parse Yaml in Go strict based on file content?

Tags: go, yaml

I know how to parse a `yaml` file in `go`, but not I have files with a different format in a directory and want to read all of them, but the criteria to decide which strict type to use is a field in the file.

It’s a bit like `k8s yaml files` where you have a `kind:` at the beginning.

Any idea how to do that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In general the YAML libraries now how to unmarshal `[]byte` or/and `io.Reader`, so you can read the first line, decide what structure to use and then unmarshal the rest of the data (passed as `[]byte`, `io.Reader` or other, but not as a complete file).

Comment: There's many [online resources](https://yaml2go.prasadg.dev/) that can craft Go structs for various YAML inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse them into a single union-like structure by implementing `UnmarshalYAML`. E.g.:

```golang
package main

import (
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

type FooStructure struct {
    Name string
    Description string
}

type BarStructure struct {
    Age int
}

type Kind int

const (
    FooKind Kind = iota
    BarKind
)

type Container struct {
    Kind
    FooStructure
    BarStructure
}

func (c *Container) UnmarshalYAML(node *yaml.Node) error {
    if node.Kind != yaml.MappingNode {
        return errors.New("wrong node kind")
    }
    for i := 0; i < len(node.Content); i += 2 {
        key := node.Content[i]
        if key.Kind == yaml.ScalarNode && key.Value == "kind" {
            value := node.Content[i+1]
            if value.Kind != yaml.ScalarNode {
                return errors.New("non-scalar kind")
            }
            // remove the "kind" kev/value pair
            node.Content[i] = node.Content[len(node.Content)-2]
            node.Content[i+1] = node.Content[len(node.Content)-1]
            node.Content = node.Content[:len(node.Content)-2]
            
            switch value.Value {
                case "foo":
                    c.Kind = FooKind
                    return node.Decode(&c.FooStructure)
                case "bar":
                    c.Kind = BarKind
                    return node.Decode(&c.BarStructure)
                default:
                    return errors.New("unknown kind: " + value.Value)
            }       
        }
    }
    return nil
}

var input = [][]byte{[]byte(`
kind: foo
name: Karl Koch
description: Droggeljug
`), []byte(`
kind: bar
age: 42
`)}

func main() {
    var c [2]Container
    for i := range c {
        if err := yaml.Unmarshal(input[i], &c[i]); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }

    for i := range c {
        fmt.Printf("input %v:\n%v\n", i, c[i])
    }
}
```

This yields:

```
input 0:
{0 {Karl Koch Droggeljug} {0}}
input 1:
{1 { } {42}}
```

As you can see, the input structures differ but the correct field is chosen based on the `kind:` (which does not even need to be the first item). You can check which kind of file you loaded by looking at the `Kind` field.

If your structures are large, you may want to have pointer members in `Container` to avoid using unnecessary space consumption.